# HAProxy redirect requests from one port to another

Tags: redirect, haproxy, http-redirect

I'm using HAProxy version 1.6.

How would I modify the config to redirect requests from:
localhost:8081/myapp

to:
localhost:8111/myapp

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
frontend weblb
bind *:8081
acl if is_seller url_beg /myapp  
use_backend sellerserver if is_seller

backend sellerserver
balance source
server web1 127.0.0.1:8111 maxconn 1024 weight 3 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `replace-value` on the Host header:

```
http-request replace-value Host localhost:8081 localhost:8111
```

Which is nice because it also supports regexes:

```
http-request replace-value Host (.*):8081 \1:8111
```

Comment: Most elegant method.

Answer (score 1):

something like :

```
listen weblb xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081
balance leastconn
mode http
server web1 127.0.0.1:8111
```